# how can i manage language locales in automatically in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I managed it in the code, but
I would like to manage different countries language in the project automatically.

```
res
values
added all language string here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created your project using the Android SDK Tools (read Creating an Android Project), the tools create a res/ directory in the top level of the project. Within this res/ directory are subdirectories for various resource types. There are also a few default files such as res/values/strings.xml, which holds your string values.

o add support for more languages, create additional values directories inside res/ that include a hyphen and the ISO language code at the end of the directory name.

Please check the following url for detailed explanation

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs